# Controlar si los checkbox están seleccionado o no

Tags: jquery

He creado un listado que se compone de diferentes checkbox, y un botón.

Quiero que si hay al menos un checkbox seleccionado el botón muestre "guardar" y en el único y exclusivo caso de que no haya ningún checkbox seleccionado, ponga cerrar.

He escrito este código, pero no va bien, porque si deselecciono un checkbox aunque haya otros seleccionados, me cambia el mensaje igualmente a cerrar.

```
$( '.Checkbox-Especifico').on( 'click', function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $('#Btn-Cerrar-Especifico').attr('value', "Guardar");
    } else {
        $('#Btn-Cerrar-Especifico').attr('value', "Cerrar");
    }
});
```

Comment: cada vez que hagas click en un checkbox de esa clase, has de recoger todos los checkbox y mirar uno a uno su estado. Con el primer check=true que encuentres ya puedes parar el bucle y poner el value a Guardar. Si al acabar el bucle ninguno estaba a true, entonces poner Cerrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Escucho el evento onChange de todos los checkbox, para que funcione en todos al marcar o desmarcarlo
$( ':checkbox').on('change', function() {
    //Boton que se cambiara el texto en dependencia de la cantidad de checkbox seleccionados
    var boton = $('#Btn-Cerrar-Especifico');
    //Almaceno la cantidad de checkbox seleccionados (checked = true)
    var seleccionados = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
    //Indico el texto que va ser establecido en el boton en dependencia de los checkbox seleccionados
    var texto = (seleccionados > 0) ? "Guardar" : "Cerrar";
    //Cambio el texto del botón
    boton.attr('value', texto);
});
```

Comment: Ojo que sería recomendable establecer un selector anidado para que sólo nos evalúe los checkboxes de un formulario o formularios concretos no vaya a haber checks por otro sitio que nos desvirtúen el resultado y/o utilizar la clase `Checkbox-Especifico` que parece marcar los checksboxs que se necesitan evaluar.

Answer (score 4):

Aunque @lois6b iba por buen camino con su comentario, igual lo puedes hacer de forma más directa sin tener que iterar por todos los `checkboxes`.

```
$("#formId input[type='checkbox'].Checkbox-Especifico").on( 'click', function() {
    if($("#formId input[type='checkbox'].Checkbox-Especifico:checked").length == 0) ){
        $('#Btn-Cerrar-Especifico').attr('value', "Cerrar");
    } else {
        $('#Btn-Cerrar-Especifico').attr('value', "Guardar");
    }
});
```

Aprovechando el código de ejemplo que nos pasaste, cada vez que se modifica un `checkbox`, comprobamos si en el formulario hay algún `checkbox` que no esté marcando haciendo uso del selector de `jQuery` [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

`$("#formId input[type='checkbox']:checked")` Esto nos debería recuperar todos los checkboxes del formulario que estuvieran marcados. Si no hay ninguno (`.length == 0`) entonces ponemos el valor *"Cerrar"* al botón, en caso contrario (hay alguno) ponemos *"Guardar"*.

Comment: ohh claro hahah  se me olvida siempre que jquery puede hacer ese tipo de consultas  xD

Comment: @lois6b si jeje, los selectores "trampa" de jQuery son muy útiles. Tampoco quiero ver que hace por detrás (que igual itera a pelo) para evitarme sustos xD